# SQL-Counting rows when a row contains specific numbers

Tags: sql, postgresql

If I have a table called tickets with a column called ticketid for example. Ticket id contains numbers, sometimes a number would appear more than once because there could have been multiple updates to the ticket. How would I create a variable to output a ticketid with the number of times it occurred?

For Example:

ticketid: 7
ticketid: 7 
timesoccured: 2

Comment: Please edit your question and show sample data and desired results.  While editing the question, tag it correctly.  Are you using MySQL or Postgres?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT ticketid, count(*) AS timesoccured
FROM   tickets
-- WHERE  ticketid = 7  -- to just get the one ...
GROUP  BY 1;
```

`GROUP  BY 1` is shorthand syntax for `GROUP  BY ticket_id`.
[Start by reading the manual here.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries.html)

Normally, a column `ticketid` would be unique in a `tickets` table. Either your naming convention or your data model follow a dubious logic.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming TicketId is NOT NULL, you should use:

```
SELECT TicketId, COUNT(TicketId) AS TicketIdCount
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY TicketId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*), ticketid 
FROM tickets 
GROUP BY ticketid;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the repeated tickets use `having`

```
select ticketid, count(*)
from tickets
group by 1
having count(*) > 1
```